# Use of undefined constant getUser - assumed 'getUser' error

Tags: php

I´m trying to protect the access to my div class="posts".

And I just want to see if the user have permission if the function getUser exists.

But I´m having this **error** and I'm not understanding  where is the problem:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant getUser - assumed 'getUser' in if(function_exists(getUser))
```

**My code:**

```
  if(function_exists(getUser))
        {

        if(!getUser($_SESSION['user']['id'], '1'))
        {
            echo 'Sorry, but you don't have permission to enter here';
        }
        else
        {

    ?>
    <!-- I show this div id he user have permission -->
    <div class="pages" style="display:block">
    ....
    <?php
        }
    }
    //if the function does not exist
    else
    {
        header('Location: ../index2.php');
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

My getUser function, is a function to see the level of the user:

```
function getUser($userId, $nivel=NULL){}
```

The function is a bit extense but it will return true if the the level of user is valid and return false if its not possible so read an user with the userId.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the name of the function passed to [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/function_exists) in quotes (single or double):

```
if(function_exists('getUser'))
```

See the example in the manual:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('imap_open')) {
    echo "IMAP functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "IMAP functions are not available.<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank, I was seeing in other site and not the php manual and they were using without quotes. But now it works! Thanks :)

Comment: If they suppress errors they'll never see the warning you got